# React Native app is crashing in IOS after adding a style in JSX

Tags: react-native

I am building an app and creating a component with the following JSX markup and the app is crashing in iOS but working in Android.

```
<Block row space="between" style={{ paddingVertical: 16, alignItems: 'baseline' }}>
   <Block row space="between" style={{ paddingVertical: 16, alignItems: 'baseline' }}>
   <Text size={18}>Quantity:</Text> 
   <Input style={{ borderRadius: 3, borderColor: materialTheme.COLORS.INPUT,width:60,height:30 }} /> 
</Block>
```

However, it is working with the below markup perfectly if I remove the style property:

```
<Block row space="between" style={{ paddingVertical: 16, alignItems: 'baseline' }}>
   <Block row space="between">
   <Text size={18}>Quantity:</Text> 
   <Input style={{ borderRadius: 3, borderColor: materialTheme.COLORS.INPUT,width:60,height:30 }} /> 
</Block>
```

what can be the cause?

Comment: What happens if you wrap the values of the style attribute into quotes, like "{{ paddingVertical: 16, alignItems: 'baseline' }}" ?

Comment: Can you show us the Block component code?

Comment: Can you post the crash message ?

Comment: No there is no crash message.

Comment: @Kuray  Block component is used from Galio framework

Comment: https://galio.io/docs/#/components/block

As you can see, there is no prop for "style". If you want to customize it, you can wrap the whole `<Block>` with a `<View>` or use the Block's props.

Comment: Where's the closing tag for the inner `<Block>`?